# "Happens-before" Java relate to volatile fields clarifiacation

Tags: java, concurrency, happens-before

I am looking in to Java Concurrency and found following resources to refer,

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html

I am bit confused about a statement regarding Happens-before relation ,

> A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of
>   that same field. Writes and reads of volatile fields have similar
>   memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors, **but do
>   not entail mutual exclusion locking**.

I am not clear about the statement in Bold in above statement.

Could someone give me an idea what does it exactly means in relation to that statement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entering/exiting monitors trigger a *happens-before* barrier like accessing a **volatile** variable but they **also** trigger mutual exclusion locking. A *mutual exclusion* (or *mutex*) ensures that if more than one thread attempts to cross the barrier one thread may be locked out until the other releases the mutex.

**volatile** variables have the *happens-before* feature but without any locking.